# Customize Amazon WorkSpaces Login

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-18.04, zenity, amazon-workspaces

Need suggestions how to automate user login to Amazon WorkSpaces from Ubuntu 18.04 desktops.

We're a small Engineering shop of 20 users all using Ubuntu 18.04 desktops to connect to Amazon WorkSpaces (mix of Windows and Linux). Since there isn't a WorkSpaces client yet for Linux, we use the Windows version over WINE.

Our Intranet portal allows for somewhat automated login process where clicking a Connect button does 4 things:

1. Use the URI syntax workspaces://username@registrationcode to launch WorkSpaces Client.
2. Display the **username**, **registration code**, and disposable **password** in the Intranet page.
3. Populate Username and Registration Code in the WorkSpaces Client.
4. Copy **password** to clipboard.

Details in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/customize-workspaces-user-login.html

User would still need to copy password from Intranet page and paste to WorkSpaces Client to complete login. We're trying to eliminate this step as users are in & out of WorkSpaces multiple times a day.
I'm considering [zenity](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/zenity.1.html) but unsure if this is the correct approach.

Please suggest options in Ubuntu 18.04 to automate auto-pasting password to WorkSpaces Client.

Answer (score 0):

There is a native Linux Client https://clients.amazonworkspaces.com/linux-install.html and it looks promising.  I'm just trying to get it going myself and can log in but I'm getting an error connecting to the desktop.  It might be the Ubuntu image we're using.